# How can husband get his Schengen visa processed when he is at sea?

Tags: visas, schengen, applications

Seven years ago, I had a Schengen visa and visited my sister, who is a Swiss. I went to Switzerland, along with my cousin; I was single that time.

Now that I am married, I'm planning to go Switzerland to visit my sister, along with my husband and son.

My husband is a seafarer and will be onboard his ship until shortly before our planned date of departure. How can he get his Schengen visa?

Comment: Are you also Swiss? What is your husband's nationality?  Can you be more specific about how long he'll be ashore before your planned date of travel?

Comment: Is your husband independent, or employed on a vessel or shipping carrier? The carrier or it agent might be able to apply on his behalf.

Comment: My close vote is, absent additional info, it's difficult to respond. OP has not returned to the site since asking the question.